# Apply formatting changes to all tables in a list

Tags: r, for-loop, datatable, formatting, lapply

I'm trying to change the formatting of multiple data frames that are in a list. I was previously using pipes when formatting single data frames, but I don't know if this is still the most efficient way for reiterating the process. Using pipes I don't know how to get the script to call the columns names in the data frames and not the names of the data frames in the list. I've included all of the script that I have so far and the script I'm trying to make work.

My current script:

```
    library(dataRetrieval)

#create data frame to attach names to codes

    df = data.frame(
          siteNumber = c(   "383652091125002",  "383648091124501",  "383648091124502", "383631091124801", "383631091124802",    "383631091124803",  "383631091124804", "383640091130701",   "383640091130702",  "383621091130701",  "383621091130703",  "383621091130702",  "383624091130501",  "383624091130502",  "383616091130801",  "383616091130802","383644091131601",    "383627091130201",  "383622091130604",  "383622091130605",  "383506091132201",  "383508091132002",  "383508091132004",  "383519091133701",  "383557091132001",  "383614091132801"),
          siteName = c( "BW-00A",   "BW-01",    "BW-01A", "BW-04D","BW-04S",    "BW-04A-D", "BW-04A-S", "BW-08",    "BW-08A",   "BW-11",    "BW-11A-D", "BW-11A-S", "BW-13",    "BW-13A",   "BW-14",    "BW-14A", "BW4-15", "BW4-16",   "BW4-17",   "BW4-18",   "MW-04",    "MW-04A",   "MW-04B",   "MW-11",    "W3",   "W4")
        )

#function paramaters
    parameterCode = c("34475", "34485","39180", "77093")
    parameterName = c("Tetrachloroethene", "Trichloroethene","2Trichloroethene", "cis-1,2-Dichloroethene")
    startDate = "2019-01-01"
    endDate = "2020-12-15"

#create data tables and assign site names instead of site numbers
    results <- lapply(df$siteNumber, readNWISqw, parameterCode, startDate, endDate)
    names(results) <- df$siteName
```

This code creates a "Large list" of multiple data frames. I've been trying to call the list (named `results`) in my script below, but it only calls the names of the data frames in the list and not the information in the data frames themselves like `results$'insertTableName'` would.

Formatting script I'm trying to do:

1. Duplicate site_no and parm_cd columns and rename them.
   I'm not sure how to make this work for all of the data frames in the list. Would I need a `for loop`?

```
    dataTable$site_nm = dataTable$site_no
    dataTable$parm_nm = dataTable$parm_cd
```

2. unite result_va and remark_cd columns
3. select specific columns to display
4. replace number codes in duplicated columns to name codes
5. unite parameter name and number columns
6. pivot wider parameters

I know that to call specific tables I need `results$'insertTableName'` but don't know how to call all of the tables at once. Do I need to use a `for loop`?

```
results %>%
  unite(result_va,remark_cd,result_va, sep = "", na.rm = TRUE) %>%
  select(site_no, sample_dt, sample_tm, parm_cd,result_va) %>%
  within(parm_cd <- factor(parm_cd, levels = parameterCode, labels = parameterName)) %>%
  within(site_no <- factor(site_no, levels = siteNumber, labels = siteName)) %>%
  unite(parm_nm, parm_nm, parm_cd, sep = " - ", na.rm = TRUE)
  pivot_wider(names_from = parm_cd, values_from = result_va, values_fn = NULL)
```

If I only have one table/df this code will work, but when I try to reiterate it over a list of data frames I get stuck in a googling rabbit hole. Hopefully that all made sense and please let me know if there's a better way to do this. I don't really know that much about coding. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't get the last `pivot_wider()` to work, but you could actually stick the pipe in an `lapply()` statement, like below.  I also used `df$` to access `siteNumber` and `siteName`:

```
res <- lapply(results, function(x){if(nrow(x) > 0){
  x %>%
  mutate(parm_nm = parm_cd) %>%
  unite(result_va,remark_cd,result_va, sep = "", na.rm = TRUE) %>%
  select(site_no, sample_dt, sample_tm, parm_cd,result_va, parm_nm) %>%
  mutate(parm_cd = factor(parm_cd, levels = parameterCode, labels = parameterName)) %>%
  mutate(site_no = factor(site_no, levels = df$siteNumber, labels = df$siteName)) %>%
  unite(parm_nm, parm_nm, parm_cd, sep = " - ", na.rm = TRUE)# %>%
  #pivot_wider(names_from = parm_cd, values_from = result_va, values_fn = NULL)
  }})
```

You could also build the pipeline function and then use `map()`:

```
pipeline <- function(x){
  if(nrow(x) > 0){
    x %>%
    mutate(parm_nm = parm_cd) %>%
    unite(result_va,remark_cd,result_va, sep = "", na.rm = TRUE) %>%
    select(site_no, sample_dt, sample_tm, parm_cd,result_va, parm_nm) %>%
    mutate(parm_cd = factor(parm_cd, levels = parameterCode, labels = parameterName)) %>%
    mutate(site_no = factor(site_no, levels = df$siteNumber, labels = df$siteName)) %>%
    unite(parm_nm, parm_nm, parm_cd, sep = " - ", na.rm = TRUE)
  }
}

results %>% map(pipeline)
```

Note, that you need the `if(nrow(x)>0)` up front to stop the pipeline from trying to execute on elements of the list that don't have data in them.

Answer (score 0):

If you think of `results` as a list-column of data frames, you can use tidy operations to filter and map everything in one piped chain:

```r
new_results <- 
  tibble(dfs = results) %>%
  filter(map_lgl(dfs, ~nrow(.) > 0)) %>%
  mutate(new_dfs = map(dfs, function(df) {
    df %>%
      mutate(parm_nm = parm_cd) %>%
      unite(result_va,remark_cd,result_va, sep = "", na.rm = TRUE) %>%
      select(site_no, sample_dt, sample_tm, parm_cd,result_va, parm_nm) %>%
      mutate(parm_cd = factor(parm_cd, levels = parameterCode, labels = parameterName)) %>%
      mutate(site_no = factor(site_no, levels = df$siteNumber, labels = df$siteName)) %>%
      unite(parm_nm, parm_nm, parm_cd, sep = " - ", na.rm = TRUE) %>%
      pivot_wider(names_from = parm_nm, values_from = result_va, values_fn = NULL)
  }))
```

Example result:

```r
new_results$new_dfs[[1]]

# A tibble: 1 x 6
  site_no sample_dt  sample_tm `34475 - Tetrachloro… `39180 - 2Trichloro… `77093 - cis-1,2-Dich…
  <fct>   <date>     <chr>     <chr>                 <chr>                <chr>                 
1 NA      2019-09-09 14:00     6.1                   <1                   <1
```

Note: Your `pivot_wider` seems to have a typo, there's no `parm_cd` anymore after the `unite` step.  I changed the `names_from` argument to `'parm_nm'`.